# Updating records in Postgres using nested sub-selects

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have a table where I have added a new column, and I want to write a SQL statement to update that column based on existing information.  Here are the two tables and the relevant columns

```
'leagues'
=> id
=> league_key
=> league_id (this is the new column)
```

```
'permissions'
=> id
=> league_key
```

Now, what I want to do, in plain English, is this

`Set leagues.league_id to be permissions.id for each value of permissions.league_key`

I had tried SQL like this:

UPDATE leagues 
SET league_id = 
(SELECT id FROM permissions WHERE league_key = 
(SELECT distinct(league_key) FROM leagues))
WHERE league_key = (SELECT distinct(league_key) FROM leagues)

but I am getting an error message that says

ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Any help for this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a subquery  as an expression, it can't return a result set.  Your subquery must evaluate to a single result.  The error that you are seeing is because one of your subqueries returns more than one value.

[Here is the relevant documentation for pg84:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-subquery.html)

Answer (score 11):

Based on your requirements of

Set leagues.league_id to be permissions.id for each value of permissions.league_key

This does that.

```
UPDATE leagues
SET league_id = permissions_id
FROM permissions
WHERE permissions.league_key = leagues.league_key;
```

Comment: I had to change leagues.league_id to league_id, but it worked perfectly!  Thanks so much